# Rancher Kube API Health Check Failure via Cluster API Build

Tags: rancher

I am trying to create a new cluster using API calls + Ansible with AWS as Cloud Provider. I have generated the required Node Templates and moving onto triggering the build.

1. When I trigger the Cluster creation from UI using the built nodetemplates, the cluster creation is successful as expected.
2. When I trigger the Cluster creation via code, the cluster deploys most of the cluster but then fails at Health Check.

I have attempted to build via UI - and it works every time.

I also tried changing the API called parameters, but none of them takes effect.

```
      shell: "`curl -s 'https://{{ rancher_server }}/v3/cluster' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{ racherlogintoken.stdout }}' --data-binary '{\"dockerRootDir\":\"/var/lib/docker\",\"enableNetworkPolicy\":false,\"type\":\"cluster\",\"rancherKubernetesEngineConfig\":{\"addonJobTimeout\":30,\"ignoreDockerVersion\":true,\"kubernetesVersion\": \"v1.11.5-rancher1-1\",\"sshAgentAuth\":false,\"type\":\"rancherKubernetesEngineConfig\",\"authentication\":{\"type\":\"authnConfig\",\"strategy\":\"x509\"},\"network\":{\"type\":\"networkConfig\",\"plugin\":\"calico\"}, \"cloudProvider\":{\"awsCloudProvider\":{\"type\":\"/v3/schemas/awsCloudProvider\"}, \"name\":\"aws\", \"type\":\"/v3/schemas/cloudProvider\"},\"monitoring\":{\"type\":\"monitoringConfig\",\"provider\":\"metrics-server\"}, \"services\":{\"type\":\"rkeConfigServices\",\"kubeApi\":{\"podSecurityPolicy\":false,\"type\":\"kubeAPIService\"},\"etcd\":{\"snapshot\":false,\"type\":\"etcdService\",\"extraArgs\":{\"heartbeat-interva\":500,\"election-timeout\":5000}}}},\"name\":\"{{ mdio_cluster_name }}\"}' --insecure` | jq -r .data[].id"

Errors:

2019/06/01 07:40:28 [ERROR] cluster [c-sgd2w] provisioning: [controlPlane] Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [x.x.x.x]: Get https://localhost:6443/healthz: read tcp [::1]:60288->[::1]:6443: read: connection reset by peer, log: I0601 07:40:24.813709       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
2019/06/01 07:40:28 [ERROR] ClusterController c-sgd2w [cluster-provisioner-controller] failed with : [controlPlane] Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [x.x.x.x]: Get https://localhost:6443/healthz: read tcp [::1]:60288->[::1]:6443: read: connection reset by peer, log: I0601 07:40:24.813709       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
2019/06/01 07:40:30 [INFO] 2019/06/01 07:40:30 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
2019/06/01 07:40:40 [INFO] 2019/06/01 07:40:40 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
2019/06/01 07:40:50 [INFO] 2019/06/01 07:40:50 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
```

Answer (score 0):

and looks like it was the networking "calico" that was causing the problem. Used 'canal' and things are behaving better.